# How to build Qt Embedded 4.8.0 for mips

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

i want want build qt embedded 4.8.0 and when build i use paramether fix in mkspecs\qws\linux-mips_sigma-g++

but when build, it error message:

Project WARNING: Your mkspec is including 'common/g++.conf', but the mkspecs have been refactored
    To fix this include 'common/gcc-base-.conf and 'common/g++-.conf' instead

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just do as the message says, replace:

```
include(<path>/common/g++.com)
```

with:

```
include(<path>/common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(<path>/common/g++-unix.conf)
```

Comment: yeah, i was successfully :D, i change common/g++ of 4.8.0 by 4.7.0 :D, it build very good